# Почему ссылки сразу помечены как посещённые?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, ссылки

Ссылки первоначально помечаются не зелёным, а красным. И при переходе на них, ничего не меняется (т.е. по всей видимости они первоначально отображаются на странице, как те ссылки, по которым уже перешли).

```
<html>
     <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8"/>
      <style type="text/css">
      a:link {
       color: green;
       text-decoration: none;
      }
       a:visited {
        color: red;
        text-decoration: none;
       }
       .decor {
        color: red;
       }
      </style>
     </head>
     <body>
      <h1>Породы собак: <span class="decor">Б</span></h1>
      <ul>
       <li><a href="https://www.youtube.com">Бассет-хаунд</a></li>
       <li><a href="https://www.youtube.com">Бедлингтон-терьер</a></li>
       <li><a href="https://www.youtube.com">Бельгийская овчарка</a></li>
       <li><a href="https://www.youtube.com">Бигль</a></li>
       <li><a href="https://www.youtube.com">Борзая русская псовая</a></li>
       <li><a href="https://www.youtube.com">Бриар</a></li>
      </ul>
     </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Проверил, у меня отображается зеленым (Firefox). Возможно ваш браузер закэшировал страницу и запомнил что вы переходили по этим ссылкам. Попробуйте почистить кэш.

Comment: Ну так у вас там одна и та же ссылка не ютуб и видимо вы её уже посетили

Comment: Вопрос решён! Спасибо!